# Form submission to email and Mailchimp subscription

Tags: php, forms, api, email, mailchimp

I am working on a NGO website that takes donations and also collects email addresses of people who are interested in know the progress of the organization.

Therefore I created a donation form that goes through the whole payment process etc and lands the donor to the "thank you" page.

On the "thank you" page they ask the donor if s/he want, a receipt, subscribe to their email address and where they would like SMS alerts. So I have the following form that the donor fills

```
<form action="#url" method="post" name="recipt-form" >
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                        <label for="sposti">Email Address  <span style="color:red;">*</span> <?php // echo $emailErr;?></label><br/>
                        <input type="email" value="" name="sposti" id="sposti">
                        <?php // echo $emailError;?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                        <label for="enimi">First Name  <span style="color:red;">*</span> <?php // echo $nameErr;?></label><br/>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="enimi" id="enimi">
                        <?php echo $nameError;?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                        <label for="snimi">Last Name  <span style="color:red;">*</span> <?php // echo $nameErr;?></label><br/>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="snimi" id="snimi">
                        <?php echo $nameError;?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone number</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                        <p><strong><input type="checkbox" value="Kyllä!" name="newsletter" class="checkbox" id="newsletter"><label for="mce-group[18181]-18181-0">Yes I would like to subscribe to your new letters</label></strong></p>
                        <p><strong><input type="checkbox" value="Kyllä!" name="sms" class="checkbox" id="sms"><label for="sms">Yes i would like to be updated through SMS</label></strong></p>
                        <p><input type="hidden" name="summa" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["summa"]?>"></p>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="button"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

The code above takes all the information and sends an email receipt.

For subscribing to mailchimp I use the following code if they chose to subscribe to email and/or sms messages by clicking on checkbox in the form above.

```
include_once('MailChimp.class.php');
    // MailChimp submission
     if (!empty($_POST['newsletter'])) {

        $MailChimp = new MailChimp('key');
        $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                'id'                => 'list-id',
                'email'             => array('email'=>$_POST['sposti']),
                'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=>$_POST['enimi'], 'LNAME'=>$_POST['snimi'], 'MMERGE3'=>$_POST['phone']),
                'double_optin'      => false,
                'update_existing'   => true,
                'replace_interests' => false,
                'send_welcome'      => true,
            ));
    }
```

But it is not subscribing to MailChimp. I don't see any new entries in the mailchimp list.

I am using Mailchimp.class.php written by Drew McLellan. i am not sure if it has anything to do with that because it has been working earlier but now for some reason it has stopped.

I appreciate you help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the subscribe array, 'id' is being given the value of 'list-id' instead of an actual list id. This information is also likely being returned as an error message from the MailChimp that you should be checking for and logging as well.

Comment: Thank you TooMuchPete for your response. I put the 'list-id' there to not show the real list id. I will change that to avoid future confusion.

Comment: What error message are you receiving back from MailChimp?

Comment: Not likely. Can you please put the entire response body in the question?

Comment: I made a different kind of a form and did not continue with this code anymore. Thanks for reaching out TooMuchPete.